# How to prevent my display from shaking when changing zoom scale of my camera

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I've just added a camera system to my game engine and there is a problem, when I zoom in or out, my display start to shake.
Here's my code

```py
#The run method of my game context class
def run(self, game_loop):
        while 1:
            self.delta_time()
            self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            self.rendering_size = (int(self.screen.get_size()[0]/self.camera_zoom_scale)+1, int(self.screen.get_size()[1]/self.camera_zoom_scale)+1)
            self.rendering_surface = pygame.Surface(self.rendering_size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
            self.rendering_rect = self.rendering_surface.get_rect(center=self.get_screen_center())
            self.rendering_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rendering_size)
            self.rendering_offset = (self.rendering_size[0] // 2 - self.get_screen_center()[0], self.rendering_size[1] // 2 - self.get_screen_center()[1])
            game_loop()
            scaled_surf = pygame.transform.scale(self.rendering_surface, self.rendering_vector*self.camera_zoom_scale)
            scaled_rect = scaled_surf.get_rect(center = self.get_screen_center())
            self.screen.blit(scaled_surf, scaled_rect)
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(10000)

#My rendering method
def render(self, surface, position, z_pos=None):
        if z_pos == None:
            self.rendering_surface.blit(surface, self.relative(position))

#The method to get the rendering position of an object
def relative(self, position):
        screen_size = self.screen.get_size()
        rendering_x = position[0] + screen_size[0]/2 - self.camera[0] + self.rendering_offset[0]
        rendering_y = position[1] + screen_size[1]/2 - self.camera[1] + self.rendering_offset[1]
        return [rendering_x, rendering_y]
```

Thanks for your help.

I tried to add math.floor everywhere expecting it will stabilize my display but it did not work.